Understanding homogeneous projective rational manifolds
Every complex flag manifold is a homogeneous projective rational manifold (HPRM). But are there examples of HPRMs that are not complex flags? Can somebody provide examples of such spaces? For some context, see that related question.

I think this entry in Encyclopedia of Math settles the question: Homogeneous complex manifold It also provides references for the various statements.
